# Install Custom Lookup Component LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am just learning LWC and am trying to install a custom lookup component that I can use in my parent lwc component.  I am unsure of the steps I need to take to install the custom component from GitHub.  Could someone get my started or point me in the right direction?

The custom component I would like to install is here: https://github.com/JPipkin/LightningLookupComponent

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. You probably want to do the trailheads for sfdx, such as [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev). This shows you how to develop against Salesforce, pushing and pulling metadata and storing it in some version control system. Once you've done the trailheads, if you have specific technical issues please come back here and raise questions, following the advice in [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: BTW - it's not entirely clear from the Trailhead module, but you'll want to install Microsoft Visual Studio Code and the Salesforce extension pack first.

Comment: I really appreciate the comments!  I've been using VS Code and have developed a few LWC that are working.  My question is specifically around how to take custom components on Github and deploy them into our sandbox/scratch org.  Any resources that demonstrate this that could help me learn?

Comment: This component is an Aura (not LWC) component, so I don't recommend you install it.